# How to find out if subprocess ran out of memory?

Tags: java, error-handling, process, out-of-memory

I have a class with a main method:

```
public class MyProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {                    
        ...
    }
}
```

I have a wrapper class that can run that main method in an own JVM process (idea from [here](https://dzone.com/articles/running-a-java-class-as-a-subprocess)):

```
public class ProcessWrapper {
    public void execute(int maxMegabytes) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
        command.add(System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "java";);
        command.add("-Xmx" + maxMegabytes + "m"); // limit subprocess JVM to that heap size
        command.add("-cp");
        command.add(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
        command.add(MyProgram.class.getName());
        
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        Process process = builder.start();
        int exitValue = process.waitFor();
        process.destroyForcibly();
    }
}
```

**My goal is to make `ProcessWrapper.execute(...)` reliably inform if the subprocess did not have enough memory to finish successfully.** (By "inform" I mean e.g. write to a log or return some value.)

How can I do this?

---

What I did/tried so far and what I thought about:

*1*

I tried provoking and then handling an `OutOfMemoryError` inside `main`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {      
    try {
        List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
        int j = 1;
        while (true) // provoke OutOfMemoryError
            s.add("hello".repeat(j++));
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t.getClass().getName() + " occurred");
        t.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

and then checking `stdout` inside `ProcessWrapper`:

```
...
int exitValue = process.waitFor();
String errors = new String(process.getInputStream().readAllBytes());
System.out.println(errors);
process.destroyForcibly();
```

But it turns out that this is not reliable. This will, in rare cases (I run `execute(50)` several times in a loop in my unittest), actually return `exitValue = 0` (meaning "ok") and print out that the error occurred, but in most cases it will return `exitValue = 1` (meaning "not ok") and print nothing.

*2*

I used `stderr` instead; i.e. inside `main` I used `System.err.println` and inside `execute` I used `getErrorStream()`.

By that I found that, if `exitValue = 1` and the `catch` block is not executed, there is still an `OutOfMemoryError` thrown but not caught. Its stack trace is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> at testingProcesses.MyProgram.main(MyProgram.java:15)

I guess (not sure though) it's the JVM itself that throws the `OutOfMemoryError`. But how can I catch/handle that?

*3*

I threw the `OutOfMemoryError` myself:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {      
    try {
        throw new OutOfMemoryError("threw it myself");
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t.getClass().getName() + " occurred");
        t.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

In this case, it was always caught/handled and `exitValue = 0`. So there definitely must be something outside of `main` that throws the error in a real out-of-memory scenario.

*4*

I played around with the memory size I give to the subprocess JVM. When I use very little, like `execute(1)`, I will always get `exitValue = 1` and no `stdout` or `stderr` output. I remember that I once had such a situation but still got some output (but can't reproduce any more), and that output suggested that the JVM could not even initialize/start due to the lack of memory.

*5*

I checked the [Process API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) but could not find any method that allows me to check for exceptions occuring INSIDE the process.

*6*

Is there maybe an API for some OS layer from which I can retrieve that information (not Process API)?

Comment: In general, an OutOfMemoryError means the program can’t continue executing.  Attempts to catch it will never be reliable.  Obviously, it’s not the OutOfMemoryError *class* that sometimes cannot be caught; rather, it’s the conditions that led to it being thrown.  So throwing your own OutOfMemoryError is not the same thing.

Comment: That's what I thought. But there must be some way of finding out that memory was an issue. The OS can do this, so there's probably (hoepfully) some way to ask it...?